# explode() confusing me

Tags: php, explode, implode

```
<?php
$player = $_GET['player'];
$data = explode(" ", file_get_contents("http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player={$player}"));
print_r($data);
?>
```

For some reason, this returns

```
Array ( [0] => 322788,1584,39425065 474211,75,1213741 424332,73,1044331 497032,75,1223804 518140,74,1127869 622836,53,146813 484601,51,114656 540925,65,452516 276405,78,1772587 614588,62,339049 85477,99,13069655 135438,86,3702239 69906,99,13034532 376565,60,294135 403376,55,173156 413268,62,349011 339269,50,103575 388661,52,125891 452907,52,134281 402625,50,102104 281390,50,109948 236592,63,377586 385212,50,103894 329955,50,104225 320731,50,103833 286842,50,101634 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 )
```

The original data retrieved by `file_get_contents` is

```
322790,1584,39425065 474214,75,1213741 424335,73,1044331 497037,75,1223804 518145,74,1127869 622844,53,146813 484604,51,114656 540930,65,452516 276407,78,1772587 614595,62,339049 85477,99,13069655 135439,86,3702239 69906,99,13034532 376567,60,294135 403379,55,173156 413272,62,349011 339272,50,103575 388664,52,125891 452909,52,134281 402629,50,102104 281392,50,109948 236593,63,377586 385216,50,103894 329957,50,104225 320733,50,103833 286843,50,101634 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1 -1,-1
```

I see no reason why this would not work. Testing it, `explode(" ", "The cat is happy")` works perfectly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that the data is not seperated by spaces? But a different (similar) character such as U+160? `" "`, or `&nbsp;`

Comment: We can stop guessing if you provide us with the result of your api call.

Comment: I tried copying the space between directly from the data retrieved into the delimiter to no avail.

Comment: @JulianHollmann I did. It is after "The original data retrieved by"...

Comment: `var_dump(file_get_contents("http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player={$player}"));`

Comment: ▲
▲ ▲ maybe this is the problem ... give us player name to test...

Comment: My guess is, that there are linebreaks between the numbers.

Comment: Works here http://codepad.org/5anCDYMa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original data is sepearated by **line breaks** (Look at the source code of that page and you'll see something similar to:

```
369410,1491,41557372
670285,60,285887
777347,41,44705
399433,80,2132002
263342,89,4893081
86022,99,13097638
472647,52,123827
278652,84,3165705
454958,66,517025
706040,53,137563
445967,61,328458
382124,68,642361
362084,66,534339
321096,62,342446
412791,54,164607
475061,60,279628
331177,50,107107
332564,56,199183
21509,99,13217389
371340,53,148963
314233,46,68904
463762,44,55836
128963,73,1034979
569897,20,4784
500492,19,4088
412997,36,26867
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
-1,-1
```

Try exploding by that.

```
explode("\n", ...);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var_dump(
    explode(',', 
        str_replace("\n", '',
            file_get_contents("http://hiscore.runescape.com/index_lite.ws?player={‌​$player}"
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Horrible idea. It will merge the integers which are on the end and beginning of lines. Ie: `,41557372\n670285,` would become `,41557372670285,`. If anything, do `str_replace("\n", ',',...`

Comment: don't know the input, don't care.. even so it is clear % 3 would solve the "problem", unless there are no -1,-1, which I haven't seen before I answered...

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to explode by spaces, but there are no spaces in your original data feed.

It is all comma separated, so try:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $data);
foreach($lines as $line){
    $values = explode(",", $line);
}
```

Comment: Updated answer to loop, but there are NO spaces, those are line breaks. `" " != "\n"`